why does Maya not select the two overlapping vertices here?
I have two shells in a object that are aligned next to one another.
Attempting select all vertices that fall within my marquee rectangle does not work, only a single vertex is ever selected, as shown in the Polygons heads up display.
In this EXAMPLE, on the first marque selection drag, the polygon HUD, says 1 and on the second marquee drag, it says 2.
Is it possible to select all vertices, when they are overlapping? I need to select them so that I can merge both shells into a single shell.

Not the place to ask but most likely you have camera based selection on, double click on the selection tool. This is always the first step to doing anything in maya open the options, every tool has a million and one option. Anyway its really really important to learn to read all options of all tools before you start working with maya. Because the options are sticky form session to session and you need to know what they are. Maya users nightmare is to loose their settings, since that would mean you'd have to read through hundreds of option dialogs.

@joojaa sure enough that is what it was down to, thank you for that and for the general heads up too.
